# How often do Words appear n-times in List - Python

Tags: python, pandas, counter, word-count

I have a list of words.
I figgured out how to count the occurrence of each word.
I now want to know **how many words appear how many times(?)** in that list. The output should look something like this:

4.500 Words appeard 1 time

6.000 Words appeard 2 time
...

Example:

```
list = ["hello", "time", "burger", "hello", "mouse", "time", "time"]
```

Expected output:

```
3 Word occurred 1 time
1 Word orrcured 2 time
1 Word occurred 3 time
```

I hope it is clear what I mean to do. I cant share code really since I have no clue how to do it.

Is there an inbuilt function with Counter or Pandas that can do this?

Or does anyone have a smooth way of computing this ?

THANKS A LOT !

Answer (score 1):

Yes; use a `Counter` to count the number of times each word appears, and then use a `Counter` on that counter to count how many words appear each number of times.

```
>>> words = ["hello", "time", "burger", "hello", "mouse", "time", "time"]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word_counts = Counter(words)
>>> count_counts = Counter(word_counts.values())
>>> for times, words in count_counts.items():
...     print(f"{words} words occurred {times} times")
...
1 words occurred 2 times
1 words occurred 3 times
2 words occurred 1 times
```

Note that `word_counts` gives the counts per word, and then `count_counts` gives the counts per count in `word_counts`:

```
>>> word_counts
Counter({'time': 3, 'hello': 2, 'burger': 1, 'mouse': 1})
>>> count_counts
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to count the occurrences of each word, the procedure is straightforward. In pseudo-code:

1. Let `A = n*[0]`, where n is the amount of words
2. For each word, let `m` be the number of times the word occurs. Then do `A[m]++`
3. For i in range n, `print(str(A[i]) + " words appear " + str(i) + "times")`